# Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter'

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, servlets

Am creating a simple REST service using Springframework with Tomcat. The response should have to be in json like {"id":"101","name":"Ram"} .When ever I run, am getting the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$88a811cb cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:603)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1057)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2508)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2497)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$88a811cb cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:592)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1057)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2508)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2497)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$88a811cb cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d7f2b5e.mvcContentNegotiationManager(<generated>)
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:359)
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d7f2b5e.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerAdapter$18(<generated>)
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d7f2b5e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3589a606.invoke(<generated>)
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:293)
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d7f2b5e.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(<generated>)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:592)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1057)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2508)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2497)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

From here the following are my java codes and xml files.

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>json</groupId>
<artifactId>LimitlessREST</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>LimitlessREST</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
 <version>3.2.12.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.13</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.12.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
 <display-name>LimitlessREST</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>front-controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>front-controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- max time of the session //-->
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<!-- default page //-->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

front-controller-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="json." />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

json/User.java

```
package json;
public class User {
private int userID;
private String userName;

public User(){

}

public int getUserID() {
    return userID;
}

public void setUserID(int userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}    
}
```

json/UserService.java

```
package json;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;


@EnableWebMvc
@Controller
public class UserService {


@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json"})
public @ResponseBody User getUser(){
    User us = new User();
    us.setUserID(101);
    us.setUserName("Ram");
    return us;
}

}
```

Using Netbeans as IDE, Tomcat 8.0.34 and Springframework 3.2.12.RELEASE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your cause is

> nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$88a811cb
>   cannot be cast to
>   org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager

This is probably due to both `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and `@EnableWebMvc` are used together. As they are not complementary, either use `@EnableWebMvc` with Java based config or `<mvc:annotation-driven />` with xml.

Comment: @RamKBharathi Can you accept the answer such that others can get the solution when face the same problem?

Comment: getting the error even if only one of them is used in my app!

Comment: @gaurav how did you solve this issue? i also used only xml annotation but getting the same error.

Answer (score 15):

for me removing following from pom.xml fixed the issue

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

as i was also using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: for me Wilson's solution worked as am not using spring boot. I was using Spring MVC. For spring boot your solution will work i guess because we dont need to specify spring web mvc explicitly.

Comment: This has worked also for me. I was upgrading Spring 4.3.0 to the newest (5.0.5) with all the needed packages. Thanks!

Comment: You saved me bro

Answer (score 3):

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

I received the same error. I removed the version.

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This effectively downloaded:  <javax-validation.version>2.0.1.Final</javax-validation.version> which works without the error.

Answer (score 1):

In your User.java class add `@javax.persistence.Id` above `getUserID()` method

just like this...

```
@javax.persistence.Id
public int getUserID() {
    return userID;
}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
 <groupid>javax.validation</groupid>
 <artifactId>validation-api</artifactid>
 <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

For me, adding the version to the javax.validation dependency worked, it forced it to download the correct version